# How to keep the selected parameters when re-sending the web-form in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I am making a project in Node.js with Express framework (though I think the question is rather general for handling a web form).

I have a search form with 2 parameters: gender and country. If the user selects both parameters, and submits a search form a server returns the results with two parameters applied. However, if the user will change one of the parameters later, only this parameter will be applied to the search query. I am using GET to pass the parameters. So the query string looks like this:

```
/search?country=Australia&gender=female
```

How to keep the selected parameters in the new search? So that if I change the gender to “male”, the resulting query string looks like

```
/search?country=Australia&gender=male
```

and not like

```
/search?country=&gender=male
```

Comment: I have problems understanding what you want. What do you mean "if user changes one of the parameters"? You supposed to control how user changes parameters.

Comment: Hi, Marina! I mean exactly what I said - user can change the parameters in the search form. I also have illustrated my question with get queries with the expected and actual results when it happens. And the question was - what is a common approach to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: Where is your form and how are the parameters are changed? My guess is that the problem is with how you change parameters, maybe the page gets refreshed or something and the country parameter doesn't get repopulated

Comment: Dumb me, I left "" as a value option.... so in the form it was <option value=""<%= gender.gender || "Any" %>><%= gender.gender || "Any" %>. And I was wondering what am I doing wrong in the way of passing those parameters. Thank you for your patient)) I understand now how you felt when clarifying the question I originally asked. Thanks again, Marina.

Comment: I'm glad you've figured it out.